# Fix random php array - Undefined offset:

Tags: php, arrays, random, undefined, offset

Im at a whits end trying to figure this out..

```
<?php

$var1 = array("one", "two", "three"); 

$var2 = $var1[rand(0,count($var1))];

echo "Why does $var2 sometimes display the error \"Undefined offset: 3\"?";

//I have already tried asking oracle for answers

?>
```

Comment: Why dont you make use of `array_rand` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand` function generates numbers (in your case) from 0 to 3 inclusive.
And there's no element with index 3 in your array `$var1`.
So you should use either `array_rand` or `rand(0, count($var1) - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You must note that

```
$var1 = array("one", "two", "three");
```

is the same that

```
$var1 = array(0 => "one", 1 => "two", 2 => "three");
```

`count($var1)` will return 3, so `rand(0, count($var1))` will return a number between 0 and 3, but there isn't a value in `$var1` with 3 as key.

Answer (score 0):

rand(0,count($var1)) - when values substuites rand(0,3) will be there , when the random values is 3 var1[3] is not there in var1 array ,so its giving Undefined offset
so try

```
$var1[rand(0,2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the count of the array is 3, but since the array includes only `$var[0]` (one), `$var[1]` (two), and `$var[2]` (three), it fails to find `$var[3]`. So you would need to do:

```
$var1[rand(0,count($var1)-1)];
```

Using `print_r($var1)` or `var_dump($var1)` might help you debug this.

However, you could just use array_rand:

```
<?php echo array_rand($var1); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = array("one", "two", "three"); 

$var2 = $var1[rand(0,(count($var1)-1))];
echo $var2;
```

the problem is that $var1[3] does't exist.